# SharePoint Preserve Page Properties and WebParts

Tags: sharepoint

Hi I was wondering If there is away to save a page in sharepoint.  I want to save the default page, and replicate it on a mirror server.  I want the web parts in the same place, and the properties of the web parts to stay intact.  Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might also look into using [SharePoint Content Deployment](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2006/05/02/588140.aspx) which was designed with pushing out pages from a master site out to cloned sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the page is SharePoint Designer and disassociate it with its Page Layout. That will bring the content of the page into Designer. You can then copy it to another file. However, this is fraught with problems:

1. Any dependent list and relative urls would not be copied over. You would have to move it manually.
2. By disassociating the page from its layout you are in effect going to slow down the retrieval of the page. Since this will also have to be done on the destination page, both pages are going to slow down.

I have found that its always better to do an export of the site and then import it to a destination site.

I don't condone this product as I haven't used it but you can also try:- http://www.softlow.com/windows/business/management/free/web-part-page-cloner-for-sharepoint.html